# Closed DLNA question

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-request

Yesterday i edited [my closed question](https://superuser.com/questions/447010/gaming-via-dlna) to specify that i will be using it for my computer, as explicitly stated by the FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> ```
> computer hardware
> computer software
> personal and home computer networking
> ```
>
> and it is not about …
>
> ```
> videogames or consoles
> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except insofar as they interface with your computer**
> issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
> a shopping or buying recommendation
> ```
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Why is it still closed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was closed under the "shopping or product recommendation" clause of the off topic section.

If you had already bought a device and needed to get it working for your set up, that would be on topic. If it was about better understanding what you should look for in an item, that too would be on topic.

Super User works to give expert and knowledgeable advice on computers but not on catalogue lookups.

Comment: The answer is addressing the feasibility of DLNA (and other methods) for streaming live (real time) video. Perhaps if the question was modified to better match that answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the close. I asked about the DLNA feature being compatible with my (PC) gaming but will remove any distracting words from the intro sentence.

Comment: FYI, the catalogs i browsed only specified "DLNA" and at most which formats it supported, but nothing about lag.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a line stating that you are wanting to use it "from a computer" is not a magical bullet to suddenly make it on topic.

If you were to instead ask if DNLA was a valid solution to your problem then it would potentially be on topic.  Please note that I am specifically saying **if DNLA is valid** rather than **what DNLA is valid**.

There is a distinction between the two, one is checking you are headed in the right direction, the other is asking for someone else to do your shopping homework for you.

Comment: I asked if there existed A solution. Is this site limited to Yes/No questions?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman It's preferred to have a direct answer.

Comment: The right direction for me would be to not expect DLNA to work well enough for gaming, as mentioned by the informative answer i received.