# Please reopen DLNA networking question

Tags: support, reopen-request

I've edited [How can I stream a game through VLC to my TV?](https://superuser.com/questions/447010/is-gaming-possible-via-dlna) to empathize the viability of PC-to-TV DLNA networking, according to [Closed DLNA question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5163/closed-dlna-question).

Comment: You added one word to the question. That's hardly an edit. I'd suggest you read [ask] and the full [FAQ], and then perhaps try editing it again. Honestly though, it doesn't look likely to become a high-quality question.

Comment: You looked at a single edit, and a good question is not about the word count.

Comment: With this amount of vague trial-and-error, i might as well not ask anything on here.

Comment: Or you simply come to our chat room and see if anyone can help you there, whilst accepting that this question probably isn't going to work out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was closed, then reopened by a moderator.  This happened because you made a series of edits so that your question stated that you were playing on a computer, and not an unknown gaming device (presumably a console), and so that the question was not restricted to DLNA.  If your question was clearer in stating what you wanted to do, it would not have been closed to begin with.

Comment: I was trying to stream a game to my TV using DLNA because i did not want more messy cables. Then i added the computer part because i thought people might confuse it with the verboten console gaming. Then it turned out that it was closed as a "shopping recommendation" question (even though there are plenty of actual product rec questions still open), so then i removed the intro sentence because some mod required me to own the TV first and i emphasized the networking more. "Is it possible / how to game via DLNA" was still taken as a product rec somehow, ...

Comment: ... so in the chat (which was moved to an obscure room with active users) i finally learned that asking for settings was the only way it would be allowed.

Comment: This site is about computer hardware and software, so it could safely be assumed that i was trying to use DLNA on my computer (for gaming instead of the usual movies/photos/music). I even found an open duplicate of my original non-VLC question while fishing for comments about the unexplained close.